# create div from each item in tags column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

My `tags` column is like this:

first row: `sky - earth - sea`

second row: `iron - silver - gold`

third row: `apple - fruit - food`
...and so on

Want to create a div from each item, like this:

`<div class='tagdown'>sky</div>`
`<div class='tagdown'>earth</div>`

```
$st = $db->query("select tags from posts");
$arr = array();
$items = "";
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    array_push($arr, explode(' - ', $row['tags']));
}
foreach($arr as $item) {
    $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>" . $item . "</div>\n";
}

echo $items;
```

Notice: `Array to string conversion...`

Another Try:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
    $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>" . $arr[$i] . "</div>\n";
}

echo $items;
```

Notice: `Array to string conversion...`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont push and again traverse your array. just print out data in while loop. Try following code:

```
$items = "";
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
    $arr = explode(' - ', $row['tags']);
    $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>".implode("</div>\n<div class='tagdown'>",$arr)."</div>\n";
}
echo $items;
```

Comment: I tried and result is like this: `<div class='tagdown'>sky - earth - sea</div>'. So items are not exploded into separate divs.

Comment: `$st = $db->query("select tags from posts");`
`$arr = array();`
plus your code

Comment: Have you copy paste my code? because its working I have checked

Comment: Excuse me, I see, you're right. My mistake is - meantime delimiter in `tags` column was changed. It's ok. thanks a lot

Comment: Its okay. Glad to help @bonaca

Answer (score 1):

### Try like shown below

**Example :**

```
<?php
$items = "";
$str = "sky-earth-sea";
$arr = explode("-", $str);
$count = count($arr);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>".$arr[$i]."</div></br>";
}
echo $items;
?>
```

Comment: I have an array of your `$str` variables.

Answer (score 1):

`explode()` returns an array and you are pushing an array into an other array
its making 1 **2D array** you can check thar using `print_r($arr);`
use this

```
while ($row = $st->fetch()) {
   $tag=explode('-', $row['tags'];
   foreach($tag as $t){
     array_push($arr,$t ));
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use fetch associative if using mysqli_connect

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($arr, explode(' - ', $row['tags']));
    }

    foreach($arr as $a) {
        foreach($a as $v){
            $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>" . $v . "</div>\n";
        }
    }

    echo $items;
```

-------------- OR -------------

```
    $arr = array();
    $items = "";
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tag = explode(' - ', $row['tags']);
        foreach($tag as $v){
            $items .= "<div class='tagdown'>" . $v . "</div>\n";
        }
    }

    echo $items;
```